# validating attribute presence with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, if-statement, model

I am trying to introduce a functionality in my application in which the users can suggest an event to the organizers.To suggest an event the user will have to fill a form. I want to validate the presence of few fields(the attribute of the events) with a condition to be true, i.e. the fields should not be left blank if the user(the submitter of the form) is not an admin.However if the submitter of the form is an admin, the fields can be left blank.

```
validates :attribute_name, presence: { :if => :user.is_admin? }
```

undefined method `is_admin?' for :user:Symbol Did you mean? is_haml?

I have also tried `:user.is_admin()==True` , It also throws error:
undefined method `is_admin' for :user:Symbol Did you mean? is_a?

I have this attribute in the users table:

```
t.boolean  "is_admin",               default: false
```

I have the following associations defined in my events model:

```
has_many :event_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :event_users


  has_one :submitter_event_user, -> { where(event_role: 'submitter') }, class_name: 'EventUser'
  has_one  :submitter, through: :submitter_event_user, source: :user
```

In the controllers I have this code:

```
@event.submitter = current_user
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is you are trying to call `is_admin?` on the `Symbol` `:user` as the error suggests.

If I understand correctly this attribute should be present `unless` `user.is_admin?` returns `true`

This can be done in multiple ways:

```
validates :attribute_name, presence: true, unless: -> {|u| u.is_admin?} 
#Or 
validates :attribute_name, presence: true, unless: :is_admin?
# or using presence directly as you tried to originally 
validates :attribute_name, presence: {unless: -> {|u| u.is_admin?} } 
# or 
validates :attribute_name, presence: {unless: :is_admin? }
```

I generally prefer the first option as, IMO, it is the least ambiguous and the most readable but all of them should result in the same function so choose the one you prefer as long as you remain consistent.

In the block form the instance is yielded to the block and the block's return value is used to determine whether or not the validation should run.

When using the symbol the symbol is sent to the instance via the `send` message transmission e.g. `self.send(:is_admin?` and again the return value is used to determine if the validation should be applied

[ActiveModel::Validations::ClassMethods#validates](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates)

**Update** based on revised question:

Since the `Event` is related to the `User` via `submitter` and this is already being set to the instance of a `User` you can validate in a very similar fashion via

```
validates :attribute_name, presence: true, 
    unless: ->(event) { event.submitter&.is_admin?}
```

Or make a separate method such as

```
def admin_submitter? 
  self.submitter&.is_admin? 
end
validates :attribute_name, presence: {unless: :admin_submitter?}
```

Comment: This is not working as the attribute is not of the user. It is a kind of form which is to be filled by the user about the event. I have made the question more clear.

Comment: can you help me with this @engineersmnky.

Comment: @snpd You are going to need to add context before anyone can help. Is the event related to a user in some way? What does the form look like etc.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please see if any required information is missing.

Comment: @snpd your revision is unfortunately not substantial enough to allow me to assist. As I mentioned before Is the event related to a user in some way? What does the form look like etc. In order to be able to accurately assist I need to know what parameters we have access to.

Comment: the user is just the submitter of the form as I have mentioned. The form is having the fields related to the events eg:title, description etc.

Comment: The first option of the updated answer gives syntax error: syntax error, unexpected '|' ..., presence: true, unless: -> {|event| event.submitter.is_adm... ... ^ The alternative gave this error:
undefined method `is_admin?' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  is_haml?

Comment: @snpd sorry about that used Proc instead of lambda syntax updated now

Comment: that too returned the error undefined method 'is_admin?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @snpd then the submitter is not getting set properly in your controller action

Comment: I tried "validates :speakers, presence: true, unless: ->(event) { event.submitter&.is_admin == true} " and it worked. Is there any better way to write it?

Comment: @snpd `validates :speakers, presence: true, unless: ->(event) { event.submitter&.is_admin?}` is a little better I guess but that is about as far as you can take this